# If statements inside PHP Curl Writefunction 

Tags: php, curl

In my function here I am trying to perform functions when files are downloaded past certain milestones. So in this instance I want to download 10mb, then echo milestone, then repeat again to the next 10mb.

The file I'm downloading is about 300mb, so I'd expect the function to be called 30 times.

What does milestone need to be? bytes? kilobytes? Whatever it is, if I go beyond about 10000, it no longer calls anything inside that if.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function($ch, $chunk) {
$chunksize = strlen($chunk);
$downloaded .= $chunksize;
if($downloaded > $milestone){
    echo "milestone";
    $downloaded = 0;
}
return $chunksize;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just gonna guess that the real problem is that the variables `$downloaded` and `$milestone` are not in scope in this function and/or are reset every time the function executes. You'll probably want to make `$downloaded` `static` and include `$milestone` from the surrounding scope:

```
$milestone = /* something */;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function ($ch, $chunk) use ($milestone) {
    static $downloaded = 0;

    $chunksize = strlen($chunk);
    $downloaded .= $chunksize;
    if ($downloaded > $milestone){
        echo "milestone";
        $downloaded = 0;
    }
    return $chunksize;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was initially a problem, but it DOES work when milestone is under around 10000, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, but never works when over 10000 (roughly). The variables are definitely within scope.